# fundamental group of varieties with the same closed fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X_1,X_2$ be two smooth proper schemes over $\mathbb{Z}_p$, such that their reduction   modulo $p$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{F}_p$-schemes. Then is it true that the  geometry  etale fundamental  groups $\pi_1^{alg}(X_1\otimes \bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p)$ and $\pi_1^{alg}(X_2\otimes \bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p)$ are isomorphic?

Comment: Do you really want to tensor with $\overline{\mathbb{Q}_p}$? In some sense, this "kills the interesting part." I don't know how to turn this into a proof, but it feels like once you're over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ there should be an argument that says your question is equivalent to asking whether or not deformation equivalent varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ have the same topological fundamental group (which sounds true to me).

Comment: I do want tensor with $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p$. Its complex analogue is  the following statement: varying complex structure( or even $C^{\infty}$ structure) does not affect topological fundamental group. This is trivially true. But I do not konw wether it is true in p-adic case.

Comment: Yes. This is exactly my point. The argument I'm thinking of would go something like, "by the Lefschetz principle ..." but it will take someone other than me to understand whether or not those words can be said in this case.

Comment: By Grothendieck's specialisation theorem (in SGA1) the prime to $p$ quotients of both groups are the same, but it seems unlikely to me that both are always isomorphic. (I would guess that there are examples where one group is trivial and the other is $\mathbb{Z}/p$.)

Comment: (1) For curves, this is okay. (2) If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are hypersurfaces (or more generally complete intersections) in projective space then one could compare degrees to show that generically one is a deformation of the other.